# Texturise web type with CSS

Tags: html, css

Texturise web type with CSS
how to create the text texturise
support Firefox , Chrome

that is the solution to use the

```
h1 {
    -webkit-mask-image: url(img/knockout.png);
    -o-mask-image: url(img/knockout.png);
    -moz-mask-image: url(img/knockout.png);
    -ms-mask-image: url(img/knockout.png);
    mask-image: url(img/knockout.png);

}
```

but support Firefox, help me

Comment: i think that IE and Firefox just doesn't support it

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately no support yet for IE and Firefox: 
http://caniuse.com/#search=mask

Also, have a look at this great [Article from HTML5 Rocks](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/masking/adobe/#toc-browser-support):

> "On the other hand, `mask-image`, `mask-box-image` and related properties are not supported at all. Basic shapes for clipping aren't supported either."

Answer (score 0):

check [the compatibility table](http://caniuse.com/css-masks) of CSS Masks. IE and FF don't support them.

Comment: another way using js ?